# Accessing author name without natbib

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I am finalizing a paper that I wrote using natbib. The publisher rejected my initial submission as it used abbrvnat.bst and asked me to use their specific .bst file (which rules out natbib).

I have searched - looks like that there is no way to get author names out and not use natbib with bibtex.

What I have:

1. A LaTeX file with all the citations added in (and some \citeauthor{} commands).
2. A .bib file containing all the references.
3. Publisher supplied bst file. In case you are curious, this is RSC.

I am open to using biblatex if that will solve the problem. The publisher is silent about biblatex (they give me the option of supplying all the special .sty files I used).

The biblatex manual is quite useless from a quick read standpoint.

Can someone give me a barebones example of how to use biblatex in my situation?

I have not provided a MWE because it quite obviously does not make sense. What I have does not work.

Comment: If the publisher prohibits `natbib` they will certainly reject `biblatex`, I should think. It's odd that they don't allow `natbib` because the `rsc.bst` (and associated `rsc` package) assumes it.

Comment: Ok. My mistake then. I am making assumptions. How would one use rsc.bst with natbib? I have tried. All \citeauthors resolve to ??.

Comment: Now is the time for a MWE. :)  `\usepackage{rsc}` and `\bibliographystyle{rsc}` should do the trick.  Use `texdoc rsc` to see the documentation (on a TeX Live distribution).